# git push heroku master fails because key is not authorized

Tags: git, heroku

I registered on Heroku a couple of minutes ago and tried to deploy my first Rails application. Everything was working fine until I made the mistake of changing the name of the app from the web interface.

That was it, now both

```
heroku rename
```

and

```
git push heroku master
```

fail because "Your key with fingerprint blahblah is not authorized to access application".

I tried deleting my key from heroku and logging out and then in again (from the command line) but nothing works. I am not that experienced with git either so I thought my keys there are probably messed up but I can add, commit and push to git just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the name of git for heroku.

For this when you are in your application do this

```
cd .git
vim config
```

And now you have

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:old_name.git
```

Change by :

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:new_name.git
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much man, up and running!

_If I could I would give you extra points for making it clear to me that there is a .git folder inside my project's main folder._ :D

Comment: Happy you can deploy again on heroku :]

Comment: Just as a note - I is a better practice to use git's command line interface then editing the config directly.

Comment: Yes it's sure, but it's interesting to understand how git work :]

Comment: Can you edit a specific line of the config file from the command line then?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku NEW_GIT_REPO_URL
```

Comment: No reason I didn't accept this answer other than I first tried the one above. Also (and just for future reference), delete should be rm instead.

Comment: Thanks, for the hint ;) was my fault!

Comment: upvoted for cmdline example instead of hacking in config with text editor (even this may be easier to understand sometimes)